# How to login to heroku from c9 using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, heroku, scripting

Heroku provides cli commands. They have heroku login command which can be run in linux to login to heroku. After executing the command heroku login, it asks for heroku login and password using prompts. I want to login using an automated script.

let's say I have a bash script named login.sh.

I am trying to login to heroku account from cloud9 ide when I run this script. ./login.sh

Inside login.sh is the command

```
heroku login
```

So far I have tried

```
echo -e "valid@email.com\npassword\n" | ./test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure you really need an automatic heroku login script? You shouldn't need to login to heroku every time you open your cloud9 workspace. Only the first time after the workspace is created / restarts.

If you really do need an automatic login script, one way to do it is to write a short [expect](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/expect.1.html) script. You will probably need to do install `expect`
in your C9 workspace.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i need to login with one account then do some tasks, logout and login with another account and do some tasks. So for this i need a script that will login and logout.

Comment: No problem, in that case, i think "expect" is your friend.